# How to focus input on a child component from parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, focus, parent

I'm using `React.forwardRef` to set a `ref` on my Child component, like so:

```
const Input = React.forwardRef(
  ({ value, onChange, onKeyPress, placeholder, type, label, ref }) => (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
      <input
        ref={ref}
        style={{
          borderRadius: `${scale.s1}rem`,
          border: `1px solid ${color.lightGrey}`,
          padding: `${scale.s3}rem`,
          marginBottom: `${scale.s3}rem`
        }}
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
        placeholder={placeholder ? placeholder : "Type something..."}
        type={type ? type : "text"}
      />
    </div>
  )
);
```

In the parent I use `const ref = React.createRef()` and then call it:

```
 onClick = () => {
    this.setState({ showOther: true });
    console.log(this.ref, "ref");
    this.ref.focus();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Click me</button>
        <Input
          ref={ref}
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
          placeholder="Type something..."
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

What I get from the console is this:

`Object {current: null}
current: null
"ref"`

My questions:

- Why is this null?
- How do I focus the input?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kwp23xk4m5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your sandbox, You use `ref` from outside class Component instead `this.ref`. Just change it from

```
<Input
  ref={ref}
/>
```

into this

```
<Input
  ref={this.ref}
/>
```

and inside `onClick` function to be like this

```
 onClick = () => {
    this.setState({ showOther: true });
    console.log(this.ref, "ref");
    this.ref.current.focus(); // change it
  };
```

this is the working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/81o1orzl72), enjoy!